# What's the difference with or without the leading (@) for a command parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, oraclecommand

What's the difference with or without the leading character (`@` or `:`) in a parameter name of SqlCommand in C#?

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = @myName";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myName", "bob"));
```

But this is OK

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("myName", "bob"));
```

even this works

```
command.Parameters.Add("myName", "bob");
```

I haven't tested the second one, but I can see all of them on the Internet.

I have tried out against Oracle, and both worked, with or without `:`.

So which is better, or are they just the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is added automatically when you don't specify it. Check the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs#e0b0ddfdcb0fca98#references) here:

```
internal string ParameterNameFixed {
    get {
        string parameterName = ParameterName;
        if ((0 < parameterName.Length) && ('@' != parameterName[0])) {
            parameterName = "@" + parameterName;
        }
        Debug.Assert(parameterName.Length <= TdsEnums.MAX_PARAMETER_NAME_LENGTH, "parameter name too long");
        return parameterName;
    }
}
```

That's the property used when SQL query string is generated for your command.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` before the paramter tells the sql interpreter that it is a parameter and nothing else.

If you omit that, it *may* work, because there might be ambiguity between column name and parameter name.

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = @myName
```

will work correctly even if you have a column named `myName`, but this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = myName
```

will **not** work, as the sql interpreter is confused whether you are referring to the column `myName` or the parameter `myName`.